# How can I get child classes to use parent variables without redefining them?

Tags: python, inheritance

Long time reader, first time asker. Anyway, Here's the code I'm working with:

```
class Person(object):
  def __init__(self, s):
    self.name = s
    self.secret = 'I HAVE THE COOKIES'

  @classmethod
  def shout(self):
    print self.name.upper()

class Kid(Person):
  def __init__(self, s):
    super(Kid,self).__init__(s)
    self.age = 12

b = Person('Bob')
k = Kid('Bobby')
print b.name
print k.name
print k.age
print k.secret
k.shout()
```

Which results in this output and error:

```
Bob
Bobby
12
I HAVE THE COOKIES
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "a.py", line 22, in <module>
  k.shout()
File "a.py", line 8, in shout
  print self.name.upper()
AttributeError: type object 'Kid' has no attribute 'name'
```

I assumed that Kid would be able to use the Person's shout method substituting its (the kid's) "self" for parent (where the method lives). Apparently, that's not the case. I know I could declare name outside of init, but that's both unable to accomodate inputted data and a no-no. Another alternative would be to redefine shout for every child of Person, but that's a lot of repeated code that I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I don't think you understand what `@classmethod` means. remove that and indent the `shout` to make it a method.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was an error in formatting in the question. It's indented properly and is part of Person

Comment: Still, remove the `@classmethod`.

Comment: Well whaddya know. Thank you! Why wasn't @classmethod appropreate here?

Comment: A classmethod lives on the class and is meant to be used when an instance is not required. "self" is not an instance but a reference to the class. So name does not exist there. You would normally use "cls" instead of "self".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that `@classmethod` is a method on a class. It does not have access to an instance's attributes. Specifically the method is actually passed the class object, thus `self` is misnamed. You should really call `shout`'s argument `cls`. If you remove the `@classmethod` then this would all make sense and your code would work as expected.

As it is, you can think of `k.shout()` as equivalent to `Kid.shout()`.